# React Router <Link> within a Ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, ternary-operator

I would lik to you use the following Ternary operator within React JSX:

```
<Table.Cell>{`${user.company !== null ?  <Link to={`/companies/${user.company._id}`}>`${user.company.name}`</Link> : '' }`}</Table.Cell>
```

I get however the following value displayed: [object Object]

When I use this Ternary operator, the value is displayed right:

```
<Table.Cell>{`${user.company !== null ? `${user.company.name}` : '' }`}</Table.Cell>
```

And when I use this JSX code without the Ternary operator, the value is also right:

```
<Table.Cell><Link to={`/companies/${ user.company._id}`}>{user.company.name_company}</Link></Table.Cell>
```

However, I would like to use a conditional React Router Link tag to create an hyperlink. I have the same problem with usage of other HTML tags within the Ternary operator.

What am I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is not right. You should rewrite your ternary check in JSX like this:

```
<Table.Cell>{ user.company !== null ?  <Link to={`/companies/${user.company._id}`}>{user.company.name}</Link> : null }</Table.Cell>
```

Or you can check it this way:

```
<Table.Cell>{ user.company !== null && <Link to={`/companies/${user.company._id}`}>{user.company.name}</Link> || null }</Table.Cell>
```

Hope this helps.